# How to onload a single web page in javascript

Tags: javascript, onload

window.onload = function;

1. window.onload applies to every documents, it caused problem to specific function.
   2.body onload is embedded javascript in html so I cant use it in my assignment

Question: How should I onload a single webpage using javascript? 
Exp :  something like url.onload= function; (specific web document)  will be a good solution to my problems.

Comment: You can give an example of what you're doing?

Comment: Have a look at ajax, other than that, i think you'll need to provide some attempt at achieving this yourself before you get any good answers

Comment: I think you may be having a trouble adding code to be executed when the document has loaded. This is complicated by pre-existing inline JS event handlers. Rather than _replacing_ existing handlers with `"document.body.onload = someFunction"`, you can _add_ to these handlers with `"window.addEventListener('load', someFunction, false)"`. Your question title is rather confusing..

Comment: what are the examples of "document"? ( for document.body.onload)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to another page. you simple can use window.location.href

Simply:

```
var url = "http://www....whereas be";
window.location.href = url;
```

I hope this help